# Why is the browser injecting space into my LI?

Tags: html, css

I'm running into a weird issue that I've never noticed before. I have the following code:

```
<div class="feedback">
  <span> Was this helpful?</span>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Yes</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">No</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">No</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Very simple block of code. Ignore the second no, as it's literally only there to give me a third `li` to help me figure this out. Now, here's the CSS...

```
div.feedback {
  position: relative;
}
span {
  float: left;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #000
}
```

Now, here's what's happening:

[image: border-left]

See the extra spacing that's seemingly coming from nowhere? I moved to `border-right` just to test it, and got even more inconsistent results:

[image: border-right]

Now, the 3rd LI has 0 `padding` and `margin`, as it should. The other two still have a spare space.

Lastly, the browser comprehends the proper `height` and `width` of the `li`, and attributes no `margin` or `padding` to it. According to the browser, the text should be smashed up against the border, as I also expect.

[image: browser no understand]

Can someone please explain what this extra 3-5 pixels of spacing is on the right of the text?

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle? That would help us fool around with this little demo

Comment: I made the JS Fiddle for you guys to fool around with. http://jsfiddle.net/MrXenotype/Z8eCg/

Comment: The guy below me beat me to it, but I was thinking of the white space in your code as well. There's an extra space because there is a space between the definition of the `<li>` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because linebreaks are treated as a space in HTML. You've specified your inner elements to be `inline-block`, which means that spaces between them are displayed.

You can either:

1. Set the font-size on the parent to 0, and then back to normal on the `<li>`,
2. Simply eliminate the linebreaks between `<li>`s.

---

A third (lesser) option exists, it's the use of `float`.

`float` was originally meant to allow for elements to be pushed to the edges of the container, while having text flowing around it freely (like images in a newspaper). That feature was <s>exploited</s> used for layout as well, when people discovered it would make block level elements stack horizontally.

Using `float` would mean you need to `clear` after yourself, by either using a **[clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-actually-is-clearfix)**, or having an element with `clear: both` set on it.

This option is lesser, because much like tabular layouts, it's not the original purpose of `float`, implementation may differ between browsers and between time periods, but most importantly, it adds the overhead issues of clearing. (So stick with `display: inline-block` if you can help it!)

Comment: Instead of `display:inline-block`, if we use `float:left`, the problem will be solved.

Comment: @Crispwind: Yes, but that opens a whole different set of other problems (such as clearing, and height management). No, keep with inline-block, it's the best course of action. Use one of the two workarounds (I recommend #1), to easily solve the problem. Don't forget to /* comment */ on why it's there, since it isn't obvious!

Comment: Well fancy that. This had me stumped for far too long. I can't believe the browser renders line breaks between the LIs as whitespace.

Comment: @one800higgins: You *did* tell it to treat them as inline (blocks), what would happen if it were normal text? You'd expect a space, wouldn't you? :)

Answer (score 0):

It's from white space in your code. See this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rUEnh/1/)**

```
<div class="feedback">
  <span> Was this helpful?</span>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Yes</a>
    </li><li>
      <a href="#">No</a>
    </li><li>
      <a href="#">No</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you have a display:inline-block.

The inline-block display behaves like this. It shows any space in the code and newlines as spaces.

You have to either manually remove spaces and returns in the HTML or to change the display to something else.